# Trigger Callback for Async await function which is called on focus event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to call a function 'handleCb' on focus of page. This handleCb is an async function and on return of it I want to call another function 'showResult'. The issue is that the cb function showResult is not getting triggered after first time and understandably because it's not part of the focus event. How to get around this issue ? This is inside a React component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('focus', handleCb)
  // I need a way to trigger below after later 'focus' events.
  handleCb().then((result) => showResult(result)) 
}, [])

const handleCb = async () => {
  return await Promise.resolve('good job')
}
```

A bit more background: showResult cannot be called inside handleCb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by calling both the functions inside `focus eventListener`

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    return handleCb().then((result) => showResult(result)) 
  })
}, [])
```